# Custom post type with slug for plural (archive) and for single

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, rewrite-rules

I've been searching a way to have kind of "two" slugs for a custom post, let me give an example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/articles/ or www.mywebsite.com/articles/page/2/ for the archive
www.mywebsite.com/article/%post-name%/ for the single custom post
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of these are controlled by the arguments passed to `register_post_type`, specifically, the `rewrite` and `has_archive` arguments:

```
$args = [
    'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'article'],
    'has_archive' => 'articles',
    // the rest of your arguments...
]
```